Problem working with javascript style "enums" in Typescript
I have read a few articles about the problems with typescript enums. Some arguments seem valid enough. So I changed my enum to one of the recommended styles.
export const Environments = Object.freeze({
    Nightly: Symbol('Nightly'),
    Acceptatie: Symbol('Acceptatie'),
    Test: Symbol('Test'),
    Productie: Symbol('Productie'),
});

Then the object:

export class Configuration implements IConfiguration {
    name: string = '';
    environment: symbol = Environments.Productie;
}

This seems to work, but now I can essentially assign any symbol to the environment property of configuration. Not just those in the Environments "enum"
Is there a better way to do this? Outside sticking with typescript enums? Can I limit the which symbols are assigned to environment?
Maybe the answer is obvious but being mostly a c# person it isn't to me. I really wish javascript just had enums.

symbol is a tough one because TS only gives unique symbol types to consts initialized as symbols, not object literals. If you refactor a little then you can use this approach. But you can also just use string literals instead, as shown here. Does that fully address the question?  If so I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what's missing?

@jcalz  both seem to address the problem. As I am not really familiair with typescript/JavaScript I am unsure which of your examples has the most benefits. The main thing I like about "enums" is that the values are immutable and a fixes set. This seems to happen in both examples. Maybe you can write down both options in your answer and explain any advantages and disadvantages if its not to much to ask.

@jcalz After testing a little the first approach seems to give problems when using console.log(JSON.stringify(c));. Environments is missing in the output. In your second approach with strings environment appears. I also tested my original from the question, in that case environments also appears in the result from stringify

"I also tested my original" This is what I see, no symbol in there either. That's just JSON.stringify for you. Please confirm that this has very little to do with the question as asked, or demonstrate otherwise directly. I'll wait to hear back.

@jcalz no it doesn't influence the question directly, but considering how often json is used to communicate with all kinds of services. It's important to have that. My project also involves webservices, so only the the string literal example works for me, but to others both examples might be fine, depending on use case. That's why I suggested you put both examples in your answer and maybe note a few differences like this. You already made both and this info might be very usefull to the next person asking.

Could you please verify that your original code does not actually show the environments when you stringify? It might be important to have stuff like that but it's not being mentioned in the question, and your prior comment seems to indicate that somehow my putting the symbols in their own consts would affect json.stringify which... really shouldn't be possible. If you can demonstrate the difference, please do so. Otherwise I'm going to have to assume you're mistaken about that.

@jcalz. I was sure I saw the difference, but I cannot reproduce the behavior anymore. So you must be correct, I was mistaken about that.

Then let's back way up. I can write my answer without worrying about JSON.stringify, right? It's completely irrelevant to the question as asked?

@jcalz, correct
